# TypeError: <class 'cftime._cftime.DatetimeGregorian'> is not convertible to datetime

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying to use the pvlib-python tool for forecasting. The tool comes with some model-specific classes.

```
# Import pvlib forecast models
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_color_codes()
from pvlib.forecast import GFS, NAM, NDFD, HRRR, RAP
from pvlib import solarposition

# Specify Location (Phoenix, AZ)
latitude, longitude, tz = 32.2, -110.9, 'US/Arizona'

# Specify time range
start = pd.Timestamp(datetime.date.today(), tz=tz)
end = start + pd.Timedelta(days=7)
irrad_vars = ['ghi','dni','dhi']


from pvlib.forecast import GFS, NAM, NDFD, HRRR, RAP
model = GFS()
# Retrive data.returns panda.DataFrame object
raw_data = model.get_data(latitude, longitude, start, end)
print(raw_data.head())
```

When I try to get data from the model, the code produces the following output:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
# Retrive data.returns panda.DataFrame object
----> 6 raw_data = model.get_data(latitude, longitude, start, end)
TypeError: <class 'cftime._cftime.DatetimeGregorian'> is not convertible to datetime
```

Comment: What is your question? Also, please provide the entire error message.

Comment: Please state which line gives the specified error. Also, please be more explicit (show us what you've tried) as it would be helpful for both you and us ( we would better understand, and you will get an answer sooner)

Comment: I added more code and specified the error. When I try to get the data from the model (GFS). The class is not convertible to datetime. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So i don't know what is in your `getdata` function but i would suspect it uses netCDF4 library. and the `netCDF4.num2date` function which is built on the cftime library (https://github.com/Unidata/cftime).  See requirements section of netCDF4 documentation: https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html

It seems they migrated away from python datetime library around version 5 because it can handle more `calendars` than strictly gregorian.  I don't totally understand why, but you can use the `kwarg` options of `only_use_cftime_datetimes=False` usually will suffice, but you can also force it with an additional `only_use_python_datetimes=True`  This should return you a python datetime and fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It was discussed by pvlib's contributors here: https://github.com/pvlib/pvlib-python/issues/944

One of the suggestions was downgrading cftime and it worked for me.