# Garbled title string in plt.set_title()

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray

I have an `xarray.Dataset`, ds, with a time variable that is:

```
array([cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2021, 10, 16, 9, 50, 1, 0)], dtype=object)
```

I would like to use the date in the plot title, as:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=200))  # Orthographic
day_str = np.datetime_as_string(ds.time, unit='D').tobytes().decode()
ax.set_title(day_str, size = 10.)
```

The problem I'm having is that, when I use the variable `day_str` in the title it is all garbled.

`type(day_str)` returns `str`.  When I type `print(day_str)`, I get: `2021-10-16`,
as expected.  So, I do not think this is a cftime to python datetime issue.   What am I missing?

Another thing that is relevant is that evaluating `'foo' + day_str`, gives:

```
'foo2\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x002\x00\x00\x001\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x001\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x001\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

EDIT:
Well, this isn't very elegant, but it works:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=200))  # Orthographic
daystr=ds.time.dt.day.astype(str).values[0]
monstr=ds.time.dt.month.astype(str).values[0]
yrstr=ds.time.dt.year.astype(str).values[0]
day_str = monstr+'-'+daystr+'-'+yrstr
ax.set_title('SST, ' + day_str, size = 10.)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: <class 'cftime.\_cftime.DatetimeGregorian'> is not convertible to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60958754/typeerror-class-cftime-cftime-datetimegregorian-is-not-convertible-to-date)

Comment: Have you tried str(day_str)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried str(day_str)-- it returns ```'2\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x002\x00\x00\x001\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x001\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x001\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'```  (Thank you!)

Comment: I edited the post to clarify that I do not think it has to do with conversion of cftime to datetime.  (That is, I don't think the post, "TypeError: <class 'cftime._cftime.DatetimeGregorian'> is not convertible to datetime" answers my question.)

Comment: why are you using .tobytes()?

Comment: I guess I was just grasping at straws

Answer (score 1):

As far as I interpret your question, this is what I get when I convert your `DatetimeGregorian` objet to a string:

```
import cftime
str(cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2021, 10, 16, 9, 50, 1, 0))
```

Resulting string:

```
'2021-10-16 09:50:01'
```

Answer (score 0):

The section on time series in the xarray documentation is a good resource:
http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/time-series.html

A good way to handle this would be to use the using the special `.dt` accessor with the method `.strftime`:

```
day_str = ds.time.isel(time=-1).dt.strftime("%a, %b %d %H:%M").values
```

or, equivalently in this case,

```
day_str=ds.time.dt.strftime("%a, %b %d %H:%M").values[0]
```

With this approach, `'SST, ' + day_str` gives

```
'SST, Tue, Oct 19 09:50'
```